# Creating quantile dummies within subsets of the data

Tags: stata, quantile

I am attempting to create `quantiles` of performance within groups of my data.

In doing so, I am using the `xtile` command:

```
sysuse auto.dta
local outcomes mpg
foreach outcome in `outcomes' {
    bysort foreign : xtile `outcome'_qtile = `outcome', n(4)
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
xtile may not be combined with by
r(190);
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: No need for a loop over precisely one item.  Note also `xtile()` from `egenmore` (SSC).

Comment: I used the loop because I have more than one outcome in the data I am working on, but probably added additional and unnecessary complexity by its inclusion in the above code. I will take a look at xtile() and egenmore - thanks!

Comment: You are still going to need a loop for multiple outcomes. `xtile()` gets around the restriction on using `by`: With no missing values and no ties in the response: `bysort foreign (outcome) : gen xtile = ceil(4 * _n/_N)` would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
clear
sysuse auto.dta

egen group = group(foreign)
summarize group

local outcomes mpg
foreach outcome in `outcomes' {
    generate `outcome'_qtile = .
    forvalues i = 1 / `r(max)' {
        xtile temp_`outcome'_qtile = `outcome' if group == `i', n(4)
        replace `outcome'_qtile = temp_`outcome'_qtile if group == `i'
        drop temp_`outcome'_qtile
    }
}
```